# Семейство адресов

Tags: python, сокет

В чем различие между семейством адресов: `AF_INET` (`AF_INET6`) и `AF_UNIX`?

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [What is Address Family?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4976897/4279). Могут быть и другие семейства адресов, вот к примеру [список `AF_*` поддерживаемых linux](https://linux.die.net/include/bits/socket.h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AF_UNIX** (**AF_LOCAL**) это сокет предназначенный для общения между процессами на одной системе (машине). **AF_INET** предназначен для общения между процессами на разных системах через сеть.